# Missing ( after argument list when forEach element is added in a setAttribute onClick

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, attributes

I'm trying to set an onclick attribute triggering a function and pass parameters in that function.
Some parameters come directly from the element of my array in which I'm generating the button in which I want create the new attribute on click.
As soon as I use an element attribute (e.g. element.startTime), I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list".

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is my code :

```
if(days[day]) {
                days[day].forEach(
                    (element) => {
                        var scheduleChild = document.createElement('div')
                        scheduleChild.className = 'btn btn-link text-center schedulesTime'
                        var address = document.createAttribute("data-address")
                        address.value = element.address
                        scheduleChild.setAttributeNode(address)
                        var startTime = document.createAttribute("data-startTime")
                        startTime.value = element.startTime
                        scheduleChild.setAttributeNode(startTime)
                        var endTime = document.createAttribute("data-endTime")
                        endTime.value = element.endTime
                        scheduleChild.setAttributeNode(endTime)
                        scheduleChild.innerText = element.startTime+'-'+element.endTime
                        scheduleChild.setAttribute('onClick','bookTimeslot('+id_provider+','+element.startTime+')')
                        dayParent.appendChild(scheduleChild)

                    }
                )}
```

The creation of the button is working and I can see the onclick attribute set in my button.
Here as example, the HTML of a button I create :

```
<div class="btn btn-link text-center schedulesTime" data-address="3" data-starttime="09:00" data-endtime="09:45" onclick="bookTimeslot(3,09:00)">09:00-09:45</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to build code strings like that. Instead, assign an actual function (or better yet, use `addEventListener`):

```
scheduleChild.addEventListener("click", () => bookTimeslot(id_provider, element.startTime));
```

The most likely issue in this specific case is the lack of quotes around the date string, but again, building code strings is error-prone and unnecessary.

Note: That will use the value of `element.startTime` as of when the click occurs. If it's possible that element may change, and you want the previous value to be used, grab it locally:

```
const startTime = new Date(+element.startTime); // If it's a `Date`
scheduleChild.addEventListener("click", () => bookTimeslot(id_provider, startTime));
```

---

Side note: You don't have to create attribute nodes directly, you can use `setAttribute`. So this:

```
var address = document.createAttribute("data-address")
address.value = element.address
scheduleChild.setAttributeNode(address)
```

becomes

```
scheduleChild.setAttribute("data-address", element.address);
```

Side note 2: You're using an arrow function, so clearly you're in an ES2015+ environment. `var` is effectively deprecated, in general I recommend `let` or `const`.

With those changes:

```
days[day].forEach(
    (element) => {
        const scheduleChild = document.createElement("div");
        scheduleChild.className = "btn btn-link text-center schedulesTime";
        scheduleChild.setAttribute("data-address", element.address);
        scheduleChild.setAttribute("data-startTime", element.startTime);    // You might want to do the Date-to-string conversion intentionally here rather than relying on the default
        scheduleChild.setAttribute("data-endTime", element.endTime);        // (same)
        scheduleChild.innerText = element.startTime + "-" + element.endTime;// (same)

        scheduleChild.addEventListener("click", () => bookTimeslot(id_provider, element.startTime));

        dayParent.appendChild(scheduleChild);
    }
)};
```

Comment: Okay, I didn't know it was best to use an event listener. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the value of startTime, since it's value contains **:** , so you shoud put it inside an *""*. like:

```
scheduleChild.setAttribute('onClick','bookTimeslot('+id_provider+',"'+element.startTime+'")')
```